# Sur quels critères décide-t-on du vouvoiement ou du tutoiement pour traduire "you" ?

Tags: traduction, registre-familier, vouvoiement, tutoiement

Je suis parfois surpris par l'utilisation du tutoiement dans des traductions de films ou de livres anglais et je me demandais s'il y avait des règles plus ou moins précises à son usage. Ou si c'était livré au choix du traducteur, par exemple en fonction de son appréciation du contexte.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C'est en très grande partie issu du contexte. Les traducteurs ont tendance à regarder par exemple les époques et les rôles sociaux des personnages. S'il y a par exemple une relation de maître à élève, d'homme d'affaire à un autre, etc… les « *you* » se traduiront majoritairement par « vous ».

Après, dans un contexte familial, les autres mots utilisés aideront beaucoup : l'usage de « *mother* » dans une phrase aura tendance à impliquer l'usage du *vous* tandis que « *mom* » aura plutôt tendance à impliquer une traduction par *tu*.

À mon avis, les traducteurs doivent se baser sur ce qui est plus probable selon les contextes sociaux et historiques. L'analyse du niveau de langue des protagonistes doit probablement faire 80% du travail quant au choix.

Answer (score 2):

La réponse (plus ou moins évidente) est qu'il s'agit du contexte (immédiat et culturel)...

Mais au risque de bousculer un consensus un peu bancal sur l'aspect "unique" (donc intraduisible) du vouvoiement français par rapport à l'anglais, je préciserais que:

Même s'il n'existe pas(/plus) de différentiation  au niveau des pronoms, il reste une nuance implicite de rapport de rangs (parfois très forte) lorsque l'on s'adresse à quelqu'un en anglais. Une nuance qui s'exprime à travers toutes sortes d'autres indices lexicaux et syntaxique qu'un anglophone dont c'est la langue maternel identifiera plus ou moins consciemment (donc aussi, j'imagine, un traducteur professionnel).

Maintenant, cela ne résout à mon avis pas le problème principal qui est que le rapport de rangs (et donc le vouvoiement) est bien plus culturel que linguistique. En français, il suffit de regarder la différence entre pays francophones (par ex. Québec et France), en anglais cela saute aux oreilles lorsque l'on compare le mode d'interactions entre anglophones britanniques et anglophones nord-américains. À mon avis, un bon traducteur prendra ce facteur culturel en compte avant tout (à défaut de pouvoir utiliser des indices lexico-syntaxiques dans le reste du texte).